# Why is my limit exceeding on the top k frequent question [LEETCODE]?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following code for the Leetcode's top k Frequent question.

The time limit complexity allowed is smaller than `o(nlogn)`, where n is the array size

Isn't my big `O` complexity of `o(n)`?
If so why am I still exceeding the time limit ?

```
def topKFrequent(self, nums, k):
        output = {}
        outlist = []
        for item in nums:
            output[item] = nums.count(item)
        max_count = sorted(output.values(),reverse= True)[:k]
        for key,val in output.items():
            if val in max_count:
                outlist.append(key)
        return (outlist)
```

**testinput:** array [1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,3] k = 2

**testoutput:** [1,2]

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is `O(n^2)`, because of this:

```
for item in nums:
    output[item] = nums.count(item)
```

For each item in your array, you're looking through the whole array to count the number of elements which are the same.

Instead of doing this, you can get the counts in `O(n)` by iterating `nums` and adding 1 to the counter of each item you find as you go.

The `O(n log n)` in the end will come from `sorted(output.values(), reverse=True)` because every generic sorting algorithm (including Timsort) will be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer mentions, your counting is `O(n^2)` time complexity, which is causing your time limit exceeded. Fortunately, python comes with a `Counter` object in the `collections` module, which will do exactly what the other answer describes, but in well-optimized C code. This will reduce your time complexity to `O(nlogn)`.

Furthermore, you can reduce your time complexity to `O(nlogk)` by replacing the sort call with a min-heap trick. Keep a min-heap of size `k`, and add the other elements and pop the min one by one, until all elements have been inserted (at some point or another). The `k` that remain in the heap are your maximum `k` values.

```
from collections import Counter
from heapq import heappushpop, heapify


def get_most_frequent(nums, k):
    counts = Counter(nums)
    counts = [(v, k) for k, v in counts.items()]

    heap = counts[:k]
    heapify(heap)

    for count in counts[k:]:
        heappushpop(heap, count)

    return [k for v, k in heap]
```

If you must return the elements in any particular order, you can sort the `k` elements in `O(klogk)` time, which still results in the same `O(nlogk)` time complexity overall.